# storing filters config on sqlite in json format (nodejs)

Tags: json, sqlite

I have a nodejs web server running with express and sqlite. But now I have to store all the filters of my tables, trees, combos, checks, radios, etc.... There are around twelve per section and arround eight sections. I have to store those selections in the correspondant user row on users table and update them when they where changed.

The idea is store it in string JSON format

```
JSON.stringify(config);
```

but I think that could be a bad practice. Are there a better way to do this? or this isn't a bad option?

Comment: You must know the purpose of the storage and how the data will be used later.  Will you need to query the data in the database, specifically will you need to query the JSON field data?  Will you only need to retrieve (and use) the JSON in its original format?  Etc. You did not share this information, so your question currently has no good answer.  Update your question with better information... or you may just discover a good answer yourself by answering those questions for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is store it in string JSON format

Go for it!  One reason not to be too concerned about efficiency is the synergy arising from:

1) SQLite's support for [Indexes On Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html)https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html

2) `json_extract`

This means you can add indices for JSON columns without having to fiddle with additional columns.

### Example

```
CREATE TABLE test (tags JSON);
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON test(JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.someKey'));
```

With the above infrastructure in place, queries such as the following will be optimized:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.someKey')="xyzzy";
```

#### Note on terminology

The phrase "JSON string" can easily be the source of confusion, as it can refer to a JSON text (such as `[1,"a"]`) or a JSON entity that is a string (such as `"a"`).  In SQLite, you would normally want to store JSON texts, which of course might happen to be JSON strings.